# RecyclerView is not populating out, issue might be with getting the adapter to the rv

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-recyclerview

I have this recyclerview that is running but problem is, it's not populating anything out. So it's a blank fragment. I was follow this tutorial on how to do it and I twitched it to fit my own. Of course, it went wrong.

Tutorial I was following: http://androidcss.com/android/fetch-json-data-android/#comment-56

tutorial was going on a main activity asynctask adapter. I switched it up to fragment asynctask and adapter.

```
public class FragmentGlobalfeed extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {


    public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    public static final int READ_TIMEOUT = 15000;
    private android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView mRVProfile;
    private com.example.admin.quoteme.AdapterProfile mAdapter;

    private android.widget.LinearLayout llLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //background doesn't seem to be able to launch so i am gonna take an alt step and try methods to update
        //BackgroundFeed backgroundFeed = new BackgroundFeed(getActivity());
        //backgroundFeed.execute();

        /*AsyncLogin asyncLogin = new com.example.admin.quoteme.FragmentGlobalfeed.AsyncLogin();
        asyncLogin.execute();*/
        new com.example.admin.quoteme.FragmentGlobalfeed.AsyncLogin().execute();
    }


    @Override
    public android.view.View onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater inflater, android.view.ViewGroup container, android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        android.view.View view = inflater.inflate(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.layout.fragmentglobalfeed, null);
        java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

        //recyclerview
        mRVProfile = (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView) view.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.recyclerViewGlobal);
        mRVProfile.setLayoutManager(new android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        mAdapter = new AdapterProfile(getActivity(), data);
        mRVProfile.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    private class AsyncLogin extends android.os.AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        java.net.HttpURLConnection conn;
        java.net.URL url = null;

        @Override protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try{
                //enter url address where ur json file is
                url = new java.net.URL("http:http://192.168.0.100/Quoteme/getfeed.php");
            } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            }
            try {
                conn = (java.net.HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

                conn.setDoOutput(true);
            } catch (java.io.IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
                return e1.toString();
            }

            try{
                int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

                if(response_code == java.net.HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

                    //read data
                    java.io.InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                    java.io.BufferedReader reader = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(input));
                    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        result.append(line);
                    }

                    return (result.toString());
                } else {

                    return("unsuccessful");
                }
            } catch (java.io.IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return e.toString();
            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

            java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

            try {

                org.json.JSONArray jArray = new org.json.JSONArray(result);

                //extraction
                for(int i= 0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                    org.json.JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    Profile profile = new Profile();
                    profile.setUser_id(json_data.getString("user_id"));
                    profile.setQuote_points(json_data.getInt("quote_points"));
                    profile.setQuote(json_data.getString("quote_description"));
                    data.add(profile);
                }

                //setup and hand data over to rv // adapter
                /*mRVProfile = (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)llLayout.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.recyclerViewGlobal);
                mAdapter = new AdapterProfile(getActivity(), data);
                mRVProfile.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mRVProfile.setLayoutManager(new android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));*/

            } catch (org.json.JSONException e){
                android.widget.Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
    }
```

There are also some commented out codes that are my past experiments. Please ignore the commented out ones. Also i have tried to initialise the adapters both in asyncTask and also in onCreate, both did not work. I wonder.

And my adapter class.

```
public class AdapterProfile extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.Adapter<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

    private android.content.Context context;
    private android.view.LayoutInflater inflater;
    java.util.List<Profile> data = java.util.Collections.emptyList();
    com.example.admin.quoteme.Profile current;
    int currentPos = 0;

    public AdapterProfile(android.content.Context context, java.util.List<com.example.admin.quoteme.Profile> data){

        this.context=context;
        inflater= android.view.LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(android.view.ViewGroup parent, int viewType){

        android.view.View view = inflater.inflate(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.layout.feed_layout_v2, parent, false);
        MyHolder holder = new com.example.admin.quoteme.AdapterProfile.MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        com.example.admin.quoteme.Profile current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.name.setText(current.getUser_id());
        myHolder.quote.setText(current.getQuote());
        myHolder.points.setText(current.getQuote_points() + "Points");


        // load image into imageview using glide
        /*Glide.with(context).load("http://192.168.1.7/test/images/" + current.fishImage)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_img_error)
                .into(myHolder.ivFish);*/
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyHolder extends android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        private android.widget.TextView name;
        private android.widget.TextView quote;
        private android.widget.TextView points;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(android.view.View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.name);
            quote = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.quote);
            points = (android.widget.TextView)itemView.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.points);
        }
    }
```

I think these two class will suffice to fish out the error. I am stuck trying to populate this recyclerview out.

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView you have-> mAdapter = new AdapterProfile(getActivity(), data);
But data is just empty varibale there. Later in the Async task you build up new local data variable that you dont use. The commented block in the post execute should be working- is there error messages in the log?

Comment: java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();   <<< this is the new local variable should be using right? so setting up the adapter there in onCreateView will utilise data, but problem is view.findviewbyid for Recyclerview seems to be having problem with the view, and if i take view away, findviewbyid gets error as well. There's no error message in the log tho. hoping to receive your next guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You're populating the data ArrayList in the AsyncTasks' onPostExecute method but you never set it to the adapter...

Uncomment the creation of the adapter and setting it to the recyclerview. Why is it commented out? Any errors?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i have created the creation of adapter in oncreateview is because at onPostExecute, 

mRVProfile = (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView) view.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.recyclerViewGlobal);

view.findViewById is having error, what could be done? if i delete view, findviewbyid does not work as well... Looking forward for your reply :)

Comment: ok i have used getView().findViewById and there's no error. Problem is, my RecyclerView doesn't seem to populate anything out and adapter is set right in onPostEx. What could go wrong? is there any way i can test out if my adapter issue or is my php side receiving error. I have no problem getting json objects in my php, so is there any way like creating a json object in my code and test it out?

Answer (score 0):

Hey your data object size must be null as seeing your code

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

        try {

            org.json.JSONArray jArray = new org.json.JSONArray(result);

            //extraction
            for(int i= 0; i<jArray.length(); i++){
                org.json.JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Profile profile = new Profile();
                profile.setUser_id(json_data.getString("user_id"));
                profile.setQuote_points(json_data.getInt("quote_points"));
                profile.setQuote(json_data.getString("quote_description"));
                data.add(profile);
            }

            //setup and hand data over to rv // adapter
            /*mRVProfile = (android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView)llLayout.findViewById(com.example.admin.quoteme.R.id.recyclerViewGlobal);
            mAdapter = new AdapterProfile(getActivity(), data);
            mRVProfile.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            mRVProfile.setLayoutManager(new android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));*/

        } catch (org.json.JSONException e){
            android.widget.Toast.makeText(getActivity(),e.toString(), android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
}
```

Here you are creating a local data ArrayList . But you set a different list named the same data to the adapter with instantiated but with zero size.

You should execute the AssyncTask from `onCreateView()` method and set the adapter from `onPostExecute()` method.
* Also use the same data variable to be set in Adapter. Better to make it field of Fragment class.

Comment: thank you, in the comment block, the first line, recyclerview find view by id, normally i would use view.findViewById, but view would be error, if i take view out, findViewById would then have red line. (cannot resolve symbol). So i have created this variable, private LinearLayout llLayout, and i would use it. Is it ok? But i think it might be wrong. How is Recyclerview normally connected in onPostExecute especially since this is a fragment? Hoping to receive your reply thanks :)

Comment: i have just uncommented out the block code, and using it. But my Recyclerview is still empty.

java.util.List<Profile> data = new java.util.ArrayList<>();

        //recyclerview
        new com.example.admin.quoteme.FragmentGlobalfeed.AsyncLogin().execute();
        return view;

here is my code in onCreateView, <Profile> data, i think its not needed in the onCreateView right?

Comment: Okay. First of all to check if you're receiving any data from your server. You could debug your app by putting a break points or just Log-out the result String variable you're receiving in the onPostExecute method.

After that, create a new setData(ArrayList<Profile> data) method in your adapter where you will substitute your current adapter's data array and call notifiyDataSetChanged() to notify your adapter and list to refresh with the new data.

The setData() method will be called every time you receive data from the server i.e., in the onPostExecute method. 

Is that clear?

Comment: Print each data in Logcat to check if you are  getting any data from server or not?